# Writing an enum to a Parcel causing RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, enums, parcelable, runtimeexception

I just posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32177391/how-to-send-an-object-to-another-activity-with-special-stuff) and someone suggested that I should look at another answer. In the other answer, it told me to put the enum into the parcel as a `Serializable`. (And if you don't now what I am talking about, read the post above.) I tried to do it like this:

```
protected QuestionOptions(Parcel in) {
    digitCount = in.readInt ();
    operationType = (OperationType)in.readSerializable ();
    boolean[] array = new boolean[1];
    in.readBooleanArray (array);
    timerEnabled = array[0];
}

public static final Creator<QuestionOptions> CREATOR = new Creator<QuestionOptions> () {
    @Override
    public QuestionOptions createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new QuestionOptions (in);
    }

    @Override
    public QuestionOptions[] newArray(int size) {
        return new QuestionOptions[size];
    }
};

public QuestionOptions (OperationType operationType, int digitCount, boolean timerEnabled) {
    this.operationType = operationType;
    this.digitCount = digitCount;
    this.timerEnabled = timerEnabled;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    boolean[] array = {timerEnabled};
    dest.writeBooleanArray (array);
    dest.writeInt (digitCount);
    dest.writeSerializable (operationType);
}
```

When I run my app, it crashes with a `RuntimeException` in the line:

```
operationType = (OperationType)in.readSerializable ();
```

in the `QuestionOptions(Parcel in)` constructor. The error says "Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object (name = )". I tried searching this on SO and I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251437/error-when-implementing-parcelable-in-android) however that is about using lists and I have an enum. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Blackbelt mentioned the read/write order matters.

You can use the String representation of the enum to write it into parcel.
For writing boolean variables you can use writeByte().
I put here the answer from your previous post:

```
protected QuestionOptions(Parcel in) {
    this.operationType = OperationType.valueOf(in.readString());
    this.digitCount = in.readInt();
    this.timerEnabled = in.readByte() != 0;
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(this.operationType.name());
    dest.writeInt(this.digitCount);
    dest.writeByte((byte) (this.timerEnabled ? 1 : 0));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to read the content from the `Parcel` object the same order you write it in. First the boolean array, second the int and then the enum value. This

```
protected QuestionOptions(Parcel in) {
    boolean[] array = new boolean[1];
    in.readBooleanArray (array);
    timerEnabled = array[0];
    digitCount = in.readInt ();
    operationType = (OperationType)in.readSerializable ();
 }
```

should do it